# Where can I quickly check if a given X-Files episode is a MOTW or arc episode?

Tags: the-x-files

Re-watching X-Files, and I want to skip monster-of-the-week episodes if they don’t advance the story arc. I can't remember which site used to list this information, and Wikipedia isn’t super reliable in this aspect either. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: IMO, the absolute **best and most complete** list of mytharc episodes can be culled from **[InsideTheX.co.uk](http://www.insidethex.co.uk/)** (they’re the ones whose titles are followed by asterisks).

Comment: I've made a list on my computer. You can pop over to my desk if you want to have a look. (I guess depending on where you live, that might not be quick enough.)

Comment: How funny. I want the inverse list. I hate the arc.

Comment: Crazy – this might be my most-viewed Stack Exchange network question ever

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think [this list](http://x-files.wikia.com/wiki/Mythology) should give you all the episodes. They released a four volume collection a few years back of Mythology-only episodes, so this can be considered a definitive list.

There is also a [reference book](http://x-files.wikia.com/wiki/The_Complete_X-Files%3a_Behind_the_Series,_the_Myths_and_the_Movies) that has a listing of the mythology episodes. The DVD's and the book differ on a few episodes, I believe it is mainly episodes that are Monster of the Week but have a Mythology-arc character show up somewhere in the episode.

The list:

> **Season 1**
>   Pilot
>   Deep Throat 
>   Fallen Angel 
>   E.B.E.
>   The Erlenmeyer Flask
>   **Season 2**
>   Little Green Men
>   Duane Barry
>   Ascension
>   One Breath *(DVD only)* 
>   Red Museum 
>   Colony
>   End Game 
>   Anasazi 
>   **Season 3**
>   The Blessing Way 
>   Paper Clip 
>   Nisei 
>   731 
>   Piper Maru 
>   Apocrypha 
>   Talitha Cumi 
>   **Season 4**
>   Herrenvolk 
>   Tunguska 
>   Terma 
>   Memento Mori 
>  
>   Tempus Fugit 
>   Max 
>   Zero Sum 
>   Demons *(book only)* 
>   Gethsemane 
>   **Season 5**
>   Redux 
>   Redux II 
>   Christmas Carol *(book only)* 
>   Emily *(book only)* 
>   Patient X 
>   The Red and the Black 
>   The End 
>   **Season 6**
>   The Beginning 
>   S.R. 819 
>   Two Fathers 
>   One Son 
>   Biogenesis 
>   **Season 7**
>   The Sixth Extinction 
>   The Sixth Extinction II: Amor Fati 
>   Sein Und Zeit 
>   Closure *(DVD only)* 
>   En Ami 
>   Requiem *(DVD only)* 
>   **Season 8**
>   Within 
>   Without 
>   Per Manum 
>   The Gift *(book only)* 
>   This Is Not Happening 
>   DeadAlive 
>   Three Words 
>   Vienen 
>   Essence 
>   Existence 
>   **Season 9**
>   Nothing Important Happened Today 
>   Nothing Important Happened Today II 
>   Trust No 1 
>   Provenance 
>   Providence *(DVD only)* 
>   Jump the Shark *(book only)* 
>   William 
>   The Truth

Comment: I tried to figure this out from Wikipedia a while back (for no apparent reason). My list matched this, except for some reason I also included: **Season 2**: The Host, Sleepless; **Season 4**: Musings of a Cigarette Smoking Man; **Season 5:** Unusual Suspects; **Season 6:** Dreamland I & II; **Season 8:** Empedocles.

Comment: I could see "Sleepless" (since I think there was some important early Alex Krycek stuff in there) and "Musings..." (some mythology bits seen in flashback). Can't think of anything super-important in the others you listed, though. I might add "Wetwired" from the 3rd season (we learn some details about Mr. X's role in the conspiracy).

Comment: I think you really have to include "Eve" from Season 1. They get into human cloning and Deep Throat is in it.

Comment: Leonard Betts from season 4 is also a possible inclusion.  While it is a MOTW episode, it's also the one that reveals Scully's cancer.

Comment: this list is a little out of order - here is an ordered list on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/XFiles/comments/33zhcr/the_essential_xfiles_episode_list/