# Is there a list of Stargate 'arc' episodes anywhere?

Tags: stargate

I haven't been able to find one, and I hoped you fine people could help. Something like this [Where can I quickly check if a given X-Files episode is a MOTW or arc episode?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/where-can-i-quickly-check-if-a-given-x-files-episode-is-a-motw-or-arc-episode) but for Stargate would be great. I'm not looking for a viewing order, just which episodes relate to the main story. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Here's the ones [identified on the Stargate wikia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs):

Each one has -tons- of episodes, so it'd be quite difficult to copy the list here, but here's links to the individual arcs listed there:

- [Athosians](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Athosians) (18 episodes)
- [Asurans](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Asurans) (15 episodes)
- [Ascension](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Ascension) (5 episodes)
- [Genii](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Genii) (12 episodes)
- [Lucian Alliance](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Lucian_Alliance) (12 episodes)
- [Ori](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Ori) (20 episodes + 1 movie)
- [Sha're](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Sha%27re) (5 episodes)
- [Skaara](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Skaara) (5 episodes)
- [Goa'uld](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Goa%27uld) (80 episodes + 2 movies)
- [Replicators](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Replicators) (10 episodes + 1 movie)
- [Tok'ra](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aStory_arcs/Tok%27ra) (35 episodes + 1 movie)

Sub-arcs, like "All the Anubis-related episodes", are not listed here.  However, if you do want character arcs, they can be found through the same site.  For example, on the page for [Anubis](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Anubis) is a link in the sidebar that lists [all his appearances](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Anubis_-_List_of_Appearances).